# Separate project/website for mobile web pages?

Tags: mobile, web

Should mobile web pages for our company website be in the same project/website as our "normal" pages, or should they be in their own project?

I see some mobile website as http://www.company.com/mobile/default.aspx which tells me they are combined.  But then I see some like http://mobile.company.com/default.aspx which tells me they are in their own project/website.

We are taught that separation of components grants more flexibility, but that usually comes with a price -- more complexity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Include them in the ***same*** project but in a ***different*** folder. That way, you have the *flexibility* of all components being loosely coupled and at the same time *less complexity* as everything is essentially together.